# Deserialize value that can be an integer or string

Tags: java, json, gson

I am working with a legacy system that can have JSON that can either look like:

```
{"gauge": 1.0}
// or
{"gauge": "1.0-2.0"}
```

which is to say that `gauge` can be either an integer or a string.  I want to be able to serialize and deserialize the value to and from the same type.

At first, I thought I could simply create an adapter for this:

```
public class Capabilities {
    private Range gauge;
}
public class Range {
  private int value;
  private String range;
  private boolean isRange;

  public Range(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.isRange = false;
  }

  public Range(String value) {
    this.range = range;
    this.isRange = true;
  }

  public boolean isRange() {
    return this.isRange;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public String getRange() {
    return this.range;
  }
}
```

Then I have `RangeTypeAdapter` that creates `Range` with the int/String value as appropriate.

However when I run `gson.fromJson(str, Capabilities.class)` I get:

> `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`

I've ascertained that this is because the value of `gauge` in `str` is a wrapped in double-quotes and that fact that `gauge` is supposed to be a `Range` or anything other than a `String` means that it expects it to be an object.

Is there any way to expect Gson to expect a `STRING` for a particular class?  Moreover, is there a better way handling a possible variance in primitive type?

Comment: do you have access and control over the bean (POJO) source code class? if yes i may suggest an answer using `gauge` getter

Comment: @Yazan I'm not too familiar with Java and honestly don't know what `bean (POJO) source code class` means, but I created `Capabilities`, `Range`, `RangeTypeAdapter`, and the class that is doing the `gson.fromJson`

Comment: by bean or POJO i mean the class that will be used to serialize or deserialize JSON (using GSON) anyways i am posting an answer :) hope it helps you

Comment: @Yazan `RangeTypeAdapter` (not posted) implements serializtion/deserialization but it is very simple. Deserialization tries to get an int first, then a string if there is an exception. Serialization just creates a JsonElement based on a check to `isRange`.

Comment: ok i got it, maybe what you have in `RangeTypeAdapter ` is similar to what i have posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware if the Gson API gives a way to do this, but an option would be to try one conversion and if it fail, attempted the second one. 
What I'm saying is to have a `GaugeInt` class that has `gauge` as an `int` field. And to have another class, `GaugeString`, that has `gauge` as a `String` field. Now we could attemp first conversion with say `GaugeInt.class`; if this causes an exception, we would try the second conversion with `GaugeInt.class`.

Comment: This would require running `.fromJson` multiple times? I understand your suggestion but there are more values than `gauge` that do this, so I would have to create a lot of classes to handle the primitives like `CapabilitiesWithGaugeIntWidthIntAlloyInt`, `CapabilitiesWithGaugeStringWidthIntAlloyInt`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String gauge = "";

public boolean isRange(){
      return (gauge.indexOf("-")>-1);
}

public int getValue(){
    if(isRange()){
        return Integer.parseInt(gauge.split("-")[0]);
    }else{
        return Integer.parseInt(gauge);
    }
}

public int getSecondValue(){
    if(isRange()){
        return Integer.parseInt(gauge.split("-")[1]);
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

so by calling `isRange()` you will findout if its `1.0 or 1.0-2.0`,
then based on that you can either

call `getValue()`,

or `getValue()` and `getSecondValue()`

which in the case of **range** will return second int and if not range will return **-1** or pick other number to identify this case

no need for other adapters or so.

hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion for the adapter, but this is not the problem. The problem is that Gson seemingly does not allow you to specify your own classes for primitives. It requires the JSON to have an object where a custom class would be used.